# MediaWiki editor with instant preview?

Tags: windows, mediawiki

Are there any editors for writing MediaWiki markup that gives an instant preview?  Preferably not web-based.

Ideally I would be looking for a window with a horizontal divider.  In the upper half would be the markup, in the lower half there would be the rendered output.

I'm running on Windows but if necessary can run Linux in a VM.

Answer (score 3):

Give [Gwennel](http://gwennel.com/gwennel-web/) a try

> Gwennel Web is a WYSIWYG editor for Wikipedia and other Mediawiki sites. It allows to easily edit pages without knowing the tedious wiki syntax. It runs on Windows XP, Vista or 7

Do note: the developers mention

> Gwennel Web is currently in an early development process. There is a lot of missing features but is perfectly usable for most common edit tasks.

[image: Gwennel]